# Unknown error between actioncable and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I used js and bootstrap instead of coffee. With action cable.
But the server delay is too high.
The following is the log of the server.
And I can get better speed by clearing the code below in the routes.

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  resources :conversations, only: [:create] do
     member do
        post :close
     end
  resources :messages, only: [:create]
end
```

But there is still a huge error.

The following code is an error on the server

```html
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:16 +0900
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Bulletin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "bulletins".* FROM "bulletins" WHERE "bulletins"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "bulletins"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (102.9ms)
Started GET "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:19 +0900
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):
  
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 3578ms (Views: 3574.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:20 +0900
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:20 +0900
  
ConversationChannel stopped streaming from conversations-1
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"):
  
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:21 +0900
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:21 +0900
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8va2NtL1VzZXIvMQ)
ConversationChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ConversationChannel is streaming from conversations-1
Started GET "/css/bootstrap.css.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:23 +0900
  
Started GET "/css/theme.min.css.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:23 +0900
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/bootstrap.css.map"):
  
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/theme.min.css.map"):
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/js/theme.min.js.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:27 +0900
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/theme.min.js.map"):
  
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 14:46:39 +0900
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"):
  
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I read a lot of code. But all I got was errors for some css, bootstrap and actioncable.
Can you help me with this error?